# Yellow leaves tips

Tags: leaves

Recently I noticed yellowish tips on my plant's leaves. I have this plant for the last 3 years and never had an issue with it. It was always healthy. 
What might be the cause? Too much water?

A month ago I switched it from a medium sized pot to a large one to give it more space.[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what plant it is from the image, can you name it please? And another photo of the whole plant and its pot might be helpful too. And when you repotted, what soil did you use?

Comment: It's not located near a light that is on all night is it? I recently learned the hard way that this can have negative effects which started as yellowing and wilting of the leaves closest to the light source.

Comment: The botanical name is ZAMIOCULCAS ZAMIIFOLIA. I repotted two weeks ago and used regular soil. In terms of light - the plant is indoors without any direct sunlight.